# Symfony preSubmit() then onSubmit()

Tags: symfony

I update the data on my presubmit()

```
 public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();

    unset($data['test']);

    $event->setData($data);
}
```

When i dump `dump($event->getData())` at the end of my function preSubmit(), all data is ok. But when I try to get the data in my `onSubmit()` function, the data is reset...

```
public function onSubmit(FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
}
```

The key `"test"` is still present... How can it be possible ?

In my buildForm() function, the events are present :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    ...
    ...
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, [$this, 'onPostSetData']);
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, [$this, 'onPreSubmit']);
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, [$this, 'onSubmit']);
}
```

Comment: The key "test" is still present, does the field have a value and/or a default value? Or does it still hold the submitted value?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Form Component is indeed pretty complex. There are three types of data during form processing - model data, normalized data and view data. And additionally for `PRE_SUBMIT` event there's request data.

Depending on which event we're talking about, there may be other data being passed to the event listener. According do [Form Component documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#registering-event-listeners-or-event-subscribers):

- `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` event has **request data**
- `FormEvents::SUBMIT` event has **normalized data**

Therefore when you unset something in request data in `PRE_SUBMIT`, it's like it was never passed to the form. But that doesn't mean, that it won't be present later in model/normalized/view data after this data is process by default [Data Transformers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html).

It's hard to give you an exact solution, because it depends on what you want to achieve. But what I can say is that if you want to modify the way data is being processed, you probably should use Data Transformers instead of Form Events.

Comment: I can see in the Data Transformers documentation, that :

"When a form field has the inherit_data option set to true, data transformers are not applied to that field."

It means that if i set this to "true" on my test field, that i unset on the preSubmit, it wont be present anymore ?

This component is really complex to use.

Comment: Well it depends on where you have defined the data transformer (actually it's the same for events). You can assign it to the whole form, or just a form field (which actually is also a "nested" form). Therefore when Field (inner form in general) inherits data from Form (outer form in general) it makes no sense to invoke data transformers for this field as its data is already transformed by outer for transformer. But data transformers still could be helpful in your case.